# Give the result of canvas.toDataURL (JS) to $mail->addAttachment(); (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, phpmailer, email-attachments, html2canvas

I'm developing a webapp where the user will be able to configure a pool by dragging the various icon on a blueprint (stairs, skimmer, light...).

Once the configuration is done, the user can click on a button to receive the blueprint by email.

I did the function that take the screenshot and it works well, i did also the PHP function that send the mail (made with PHPmailer) and it work too.

**My problem is that I can't find a way to attach the result of my screenshot which is stored in the JS variable "url" and gave to the html in the id "linkImg"** :

```js
function getPNG(){
  html2canvas(document.querySelector("#plan")).then(canvas => {
    document.getElementById("box1").appendChild(canvas)
    var url = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
    const linkImg = document.getElementById("linkImg");
    linkImg.href=url;
    linkImg.download="plan.png";
  });
}
```

Here the code of php part that i need to fill :

```html
<?php
  $mail->addAttachment();
?>
```

I tried to give as argument : '$(#linkImg)' but without surprise it does not work.

I thank you by advance for any help. Have a good dayy

Answer (score 0):

The image is in the browser, but your PHP code is on your server, so you have to pass the image data from the browser to the server. The best way to do that is with [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). [Here's an example](https://www.askingbox.com/tutorial/send-html5-canvas-as-image-to-server) showing how to send canvas data using fetch. On the server side, you will need to decode the `data` URL:

```
$img = $_POST['img'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
```

and then you will be able to add it to your email message directly, without going via a file, using [`addStringAttachment()`](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer-PHPMailer-PHPMailer.html#method_addStringAttachment):

```
$mail->addStringAttachment($data, 'image.png');
```

Comment: Hello @Synchro thank you for the answer !

I followed the exemple but i still got an error from the argument $data putted in file_put_contents($file, $data) :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vy2m.png

Comment: You don't need to use `file_put_contents` at all with the method I suggested?

Comment: No i don't but i used it to check that the data was not empty. I tried without it too and the error occurs at `$img = $_POST['img'];` and at `addStringAttachment($data, 'image.png');`. I think your method work well with a canvas stored in the html from the load of the page but not with a newly added canvas (from my screenshot). I'm almost there but there is something I'm missing.

Comment: update : i tried to `name` img an `img` stored in the page (not from a screenshot) and i still have the same error : _Undefined index in C:\ ..._

Comment: The back-end absolutely does not care (or even know) when the canvas came into existence; it only cares about the data that you submit in your request, so inspect your requests in the browser, and dump them on the server end to be absolutely sure what you are getting. Don't assume that anything is working, **check it**.